# How can I add a combination of digits to each word in file?

Tags: python

I need to append every combination of 2 digits (i.e. from 00 to 99) to each word in a text file.

For example:

```
word
```

Becomes:

```
word00
word01
word02
...etc
word99
```

I have a text file that contains hundreds of words that should have these 2 digits combination on the end. How can I read through every line in my text file and create these new words?


This is what I've got so far

```
import itertools

# open file with words
f = open("createwords.txt", "r")

# read file
altern = f.read()

# store words from file
first_half_password = str(altern)

# numbers to append to word
digits = '0123456789'

for c in itertools.product(digits, repeat=2):
    password = first_half_password+''.join(c)
    print (password)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. The code you've provided is a good starting point, but where exactly are you stuck? Currently, running this code will read only a single line and output every product of 0-9 added onto the single word. So you need to think next of two things: 1) How to loop through every word in the text file, and 2) Whether or not you actually want all 2-repeat products of 0-9 added onto the word [your 2nd paragraphs suggests you may only want 1 double digit number per word?]

Comment: Thanks for replying back. I'm not too sure how to read each word and append the numbers 1-99 to each word consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
import itertools

digits = '0123456789'
with open("output.txt", "w+") as new_file:
    with open('createwords.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            for c in itertools.product(digits, repeat=2):
                number = ''.join(i for i in c)
                new_file.write(''.join([line.rstrip(), number, '\n']))
```

Bit of explanation too:

`for c in itertools.product(digits, repeat=2)` - `c` will return a tuple of the numbers you want, i.e. (0, 0). So you'll need to parse this into a proper number by using the join method on the next line. Finally, you will output the new line into the separate txt file as a combination of 3 things: the original line, the new number, and a '\n' character, which tells the txt file to carriage return to the new line.

Alternatively, you can substitute the `itertools.product` for an iteration through 100, eg `r in range(100)` and format the string according to blhsing's answer [which is now deleted, but was basically `"%02d" % (r,)`] or `r.zfill(2)`.